# NET 7: gRPC service: how to pass CancellationToken?

Tags: grpc, .net-7.0

I use VS2022 and developing NET 7 service gRPC+JsonTranscoding.
How to pass CancellationToken   to REST (by fact grpc) methods?  Does it makes sense to pass it?